# How to set value from<security:authentication/> to the parameter with <c:set>

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security, jsp-tags

I have a problem in my jsp page. I use Spring security and I need to get a name of the authentificated user, for this I use the next tag

```
 <security:authentication property="name" />
```

I need to compare this value with other String, how can I do this?
I thought I can set this value to some parameter like

```
<c:set var="userName" value="<security:authentication property='name'/>"scope="page" />
```

and then to compare my values

```
<c:when test="${(params.userSelect.login eq pageScope.userName)}">
```

but this doesn't work. I get the name from `<security:authentication property="name" />` (I can view it on jsp page), but I can't compare this values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c:set can take the content of the body in as the value.

```
<c:set var="userName"><security:authentication property="name" /></c:set>
```